# Why does ReachFramework assembly exist?

Tags: .net, interop, .net-4.5

Surprisingly, I have not found any authoritative information on the reason for the existence of ReachFramework assembly. I have noticed it contains helpful classes and constructs to perform Interop to the unmanaged code from the Managed world.

But, why does ReachFramework exist ?